# Resized image turns green-ish? Any Ideas?

Tags: php, image-processing

We have a pretty standard implementation of image resizing in PHP.  However, some images are coming out with a greenish-tint.

Here's the original:
http://www.capitallightingfixture.com/product_images/3979WG-514.jpg

Here's the resized:
http://www.capitallightingfixture.com/product_images/5-3979WG-514.jpg

I've checked the color profile on the original jpg and it's RGB.

Here's the resize portion of my PHP:

```
    if (function_exists("gd_info")){
        $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);    
        }else{
        $dst_img = imagecreate($thumb_width,$thumb_height);     
        }

    if(@imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$origw,$origh)){
        }else{
        imagecopyresized($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$origw,$origh);
        }       
    imagedestroy($src_img);

        imagejpeg($dst_img, '', 85);
```

Comment: What bit depth are the images?

Comment: Most likely a colour profile issue I'd say. Can you check in Photoshop whether the original image has a profile embedded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RGB is not a color profile, it's a color *space*. Valid color profiles would be (for example) sRGB and Adobe RGB. If you check the images you linked to, you'll see the original has an sRGB IEC61966-2.1 color profile embedded, and the resized has no color profile, so it's going to be shown differently based on which profile it is assumed to have.

Unfortunately, I don't think the GD image functions in PHP pay any attention to the color profile. You can try saving out images for web via Photoshop where they're converted to a generic sRGB profile, or use ImageMagick to do the resizing (which I believe *is* color profile aware).

Comment: Okay and +1, but how to fix it? Assuming the original is what it is supposed to look like. Does he need to save it in Photoshop entirely sans profile?

Comment: sRGB was designed to be very close to what you'd obtain without a profile, so I don't understand how it would result in such a large difference.

Comment: @Mark Without a definition of what real world color a value represents, which is what a color profile defines, there is no way of representing color absolutely. What you're saying is that sRGB is designed to be "very close to what you'd obtain [with any one of thousands of different monitors interpreting color values hundreds of different ways]". Hopefully you can see the error in that logic.

Comment: No error in my logic at all, it was the design goal of sRGB to provide a concrete definition of the "average" uncorrected monitor. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srgb#Background : "one can generally assume, in the absence of embedded profiles or any other information, that any 8-bit-per-channel image file or any 8-bit-per-channel image API or device interface can be treated as being in the sRGB color space."

Comment: The problem is, the problem isn't that simple. Most people don't assume anything about color profiles, and those of us that have the misfortune of dealing with them don't have the luxury of assuming what color profile an image is using. Statistically speaking, an image is more likely to be some flavor of sRGB, but that doesn't help you much when it isn't.